# how install mysql 5.6 and mysql workbench 6.0.9 on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander  (64 bit System) .
I want to install mysql 5.6 and workbench 6.0.9  on it.
how i do it please describe step by step?

Answer (score 2):

**MySql server 64-Bit**

open your terminal and paste these line after line

```
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/mysql-5.6.16-debian6.0-x86_64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-5.6.16-debian6.0-x86_64.deb
```

That will install MySQL server.

**MySQL Workbench 64-bit**

open your terminal and paste these line after line

```
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-workbench-community-6.0.9-1ubu1310-amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community-6.0.9-1ubu1310-amd64.deb
```

That will install MySQL workbench.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has its own `apt` repository: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/

- Backup your databases first: `mysqldump -u root --all-databases > mysql.dump`
- Check what's installed: `dpkg -l | grep mysql`
- Remove all the installed MySQL packages
- Follow the steps in the guide, use the same root password as before

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

http://opensourcedbms.com/dbms/install-mysql-5-6-ubuntu-13-10-x64-debian-linux/

On this link you have some manual.